# How to create any number of different levels without having to create duplicate code for each SKS level? Spritekit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

A SKScene (.swift file) object can be can be loaded with any scene (.sks) file. This allows you to create mulitple .sks files and load any of them with the same SkScene object. GameScene.swift for example could be instantiated with Level_1.sks or Level_2.sks. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: what have you tried so far? what searches have you made? do you have any code to show? have you tried it and it's not working? Basically it looks like you are just asking someone to figure this out for you

Comment: How do you go from GameScene.swift to Level_1.sks and Level_2.sks if you instantiate the former?

Comment: I have created a game with a single game scene (GameScene.swift) file that has more than two dozen levels.

Comment: add examples of idea and code, maybe do you want to create a base scene and in the swift file take different behaviors of each.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this is the correct approach to make multiple levels, but if you wanna reach this goal simple put in your scene editor with the Scene select click on [Custom Class Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gtLc.png) and write the class name you want (GameScene for example)